# Navigating from Storyboard that has no NIB

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Using storyboard, I created a tab-bar app with 5 tabs in it. So the initial view - the tab-bar view - has no NIB, as its simply created with storyboard.
Everything works perfectly well - but what if I wanted to programmatically load other view-controllers on top of this tab-bar view?
If it had its own Nib/View, I could do

```
[self presentModalViewController:openingVC animated:YES];
```

or
    `[self.view addSubview:specialVC.view];`

But being that there is no "self" to begin with, I can't load another view onto "self." 

I tried using storyboard code with

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

but that's not working.
Am I going to have to create a tab-bar View Controller (with a ".h", ".m", and ".xib" files) and make the storyboard's initial screen be of that class?
Almost seems to defeat the purpose of storyboarding...

any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably look closer at why `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` isn't working as that's the likely path to where you want to go with a storyboard.  (By the way, this, `[self.view addSubview:specialVC.view];`, is wrong for all kinds of reasons.)

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:specialVC.view];` was a last-resort. I'm looking to do `[self presentModalViewController:openingVC animated:YES];`  But regardless, for starters, are you saying you CAN navigate to a different view from that initial storyboard's screen/view? If so, how? The only sort of view I seem to be able to display on or from the initial storyboard's screen right now is a UIAlertView. That's done with `[alertView show]`  But everything else needs some kind of a `[self ...]` statement. Even when I create a custom UIView completely with code - I can't display it. So how is this done?

Comment: You can certainly navigate to a different **view controller**.  (Ignore views for the moment; they're tied to view controllers and just come along for the ride.)  You talk about not having `self` to work with but usually you should be creating a custom view controller and assigning it as the class of the initial controller in the storyboard.  Then when the app starts, the code of your custom class is run to handle user interaction and is the `self` you need for moving to a different controller.

Comment: Also...if you haven't gone through this tutorial, you should: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: k, I'll look into this - unfortunately gotta run to a meeting now. (love those meetings...) Anyway - thank you